# Projectile motion for box 2d body

Tags: box

How to implement the projectile motion for a box2d body in cocs2dx....

```
newX = b4->GetPosition().x + cos(60.0);
newY = b4->GetPosition().y + sin(60.0);
```

is this a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that initial Velocity of object, angle, gravity= 9.81 and time should be start from zero.

```
 while(count <   10)
            {
                // this is formula for trajectory 
                // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion
                x = initialVelocity * time * Math.Cos(angle);
                y = initialVelocity * time * Math.Sin(angle) - 0.5f * gravity * time * time;
                count++;
                time += 0.1f;
            }
```